# Good broad review of network modeling for quant finance?

Tags: correlation, multi-agent-simulations

Trying to find some good review of agent-based models for quantitative finance, covering opinion dynamics, correlated behavior, etc. Are there any articles or books that cover major advances in these areas?

Comment: Not sure what exactly what you are looking for but one of the main papers in heterogeneous beliefs in asset pricing is this one: http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=473102